# NSNotificationcenter for app in suspended state

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I used the `NSNotificationcenter` to implement an event listener on a change in connectivity.  When the user connects or disconnects from a WiFi network. Is it possible for this notification to be sent to the app while the app is in suspended mode?

It must be possible to do this, thinking about Skype for example how do it receive an incoming Skype call?

This is how I add my observer

```objc
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible for a regular app. Skype will be registered as a background app of type voip which have more abilities to execute in the background than do regular apps.
There are 4 types of background app: audio, voip, location, newstand.

If an app is not one of these types then if its suspended the only way it can execute again is via the user either tapping the app's icon or responding to a local or remote notification.

Comment: Really?  It's seems limiting versus Android.  So there is no way develop an app on IPhone which "awake" on internal events?  Isn't that what local notifications are?  They only work when the app is in foreground and active?

Comment: Yes really. ANd yes it is extremely limiting compared to other OSs. Local notifications are not the same as a timer event - if you are in foreground your app will receive the local notification, if you are in the background or suspended the user will actually see the notification. A user would never see a timer event so they are not the same. And no you can't use a timer event to awaken you app.